# Is there a way to get the names of the rules antlr tried to match on 'no viable alternative exception'?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

The following snippet shows expressions in the language called blaise. Antlr complains on this  [test case](https://gist.github.com/miraselimo/e52262743ed25003abc8ef10bb597168) at line 7 because the rule `funcall` is defined below to contain a non empty list of expressions between the () . This is the output:

```
line 7:11 no viable alternative at input 'pi()'
line 7:10 mismatched input '(' expecting '.'
```

I figured that the grammar is ambiguous, thats why the no viable alternative exception gets thrown.

```
expr        :   aexpr  
        |   bexpr
        ;

aexpr       :   NUM 
        |   IDENTIFIER
        |   aexpr binop aexpr 
        |   '(' aexpr ')'
        |   funcall
        |   '-' aexpr
        ;

binop       :  '*' | '+' | '-' | '**' | '/'
        ;

bexpr       :   aexpr relop aexpr 
        |   bexpr ('\\/' | '/\\') bexpr
        |   '-' bexpr
        |   NUM
//            |   IDENTIFIER 
        |   funcall
        ;

relop       :  '=' | '~' | '<' | '<=' | '>=' | '>'
        ;

funcall     :   IDENTIFIER '('expr (',' expr)*')'
        ;
```

[Link to full grammar](https://gist.github.com/miraselimo/e21c6029fd797a542310d9a82d55554d).

I'm really interested to get enough information as possible from the tool as which rules Antlr tried to match before throwing the exception. I did go through the chapter on Error recovery and strategy in the book. From the book, the least I could find is that its possible to override the `reportNoViableAlternative` as :

```
public class MyErrorStrategy extends DefaultErrorStrategy {
    @Override
    public void reportNoViableAlternative(Parser parser,
                                      NoViableAltException e)
        throws RecognitionException
    {
       // ANTLR generates Parser subclasses from grammars and
    // Parser extends Recognizer. Parameter parser is a
    // pointer to the parser that detected the error
    String msg = "can't choose between alternatives"; // nonstandard msg
    parser.notifyErrorListeners(e.getOffendingToken(), msg, e);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to build from here and get the rules Antlr tried to match?

Comment: At the point of the error you should have a partial parse tree for everything that matched so far. However, due to the infinite lookahead it can happen that the error appears way earlier in the parsing process, even before a rule was actually matched and makes the top level rule not matching anything, even though a certain prefix of the input would match. That makes it difficult to find the real parse error location.

Comment: It doesn't seem ``pi()`` is syntactically allowed since the function call rule is: ``IDENTIFIER '('expr (',' expr)*')'``. expr can't be empty.